# Xmlstarlet sel command in a bash script - Delete a tag

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

The concerned xml file:

```
<properties>
    <structure name="preference">
        <structure name="cam1">
            <property name="number" value="8"/>
            <property name="name" value="eddi"/>
        </structure>
        <structure name="cam2">
            <property name="number" value="2"/>
            <property name="name" value="franck"/>
        </structure>
    </structure>
</properties>
```

In my bash script, I want to insert the value "8" in a variable then use it in a condition (if). If the value is equal to "8" I have to delete the structure "cam1".

So, I'm trying to use xmlstarlet tool with this command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/properties/structure[@name="preference"]/structure[@name="cam1"]/property[@name="number"]/@value' -v . -n file.xml
```

This was the command to use in a terminal to get the value, in the script I wrote it this way:

```
camera=`xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m \'/properties/structure[@name=\"preference\"]/structure[@name=\"cam1\"]/property[@name=\"number\"]/@value\' -v . -n $1`
```

then try to print the variable:

```
echo $camera
```

of course I don't have my result "8" printed, I think I have a problem with the backflash...
is there an other way to delete easily the structure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how you're determining where the "8" comes from. Why extract the value to use as a comparison in the delete?

Here's an example that will delete the `structure` element when the child `property` element, with the `name` attribute value of `number`, has a `value` attribute with the value of `8`.

Hope this helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

toDelete="8"
modXML=$(xmlstarlet ed -d "/properties/structure[@name='preference']/structure[property[@name='number']/@value=$toDelete]" $1)

echo $modXML
```